# Troubles with PDF export

Tags: xetex

I installed, in the following order, TExlive and lyx, on the MacBook Pro. When I try to export a ".lyx" file to a pdf file, the operation fails. I am NOT able to generate a PDF. When I try to generate a pdf file, starting from a lyx file, the program gives an error message. I tried to change the settings but I couldn't. Conversely, exporting a lyx file to an xhtml file works fine
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This is the same as [yesterday's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574146/82917), isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export a .lyx file to PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574146/export-a-lyx-file-to-pdf)

Comment: When you ask a question about an error message you should always copy the message into your question - if we don't know what the error message is then we cannot solve the problem. If the error message is in another language then provide both the original message and a translation into English.